# Identity 3.0 Email validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

Hello how to configure Identity 3.0 to require unique email, because in my project it doesn't? Is there any way to set this rule? Or should I build my own validator? Because now it only checks if user name exists, but allows multiple users with same email to register. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There is an option when trying to create identity:

```
options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030464/2524589

Basically, the `UserValidator` object has a property called `RequireUniqueEmail` that you should be able to set and make emails unique whenever you attempt to create a new user. Assuming you use the Identity Framework to do so.