# Equivalent of ValidateEntity in Core3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

It seems 
 protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity 
is removed from IdentityDbContext class in packages ( Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore) in latest versions (2.2.0 and 3.0)

How can I validate database in Core 3.0 or Core 2.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that it was a long time ago but I hope it helps people with futures issues with this topic like me,

I was checking how to do it from Asp.net core 2.2 and I Found this Issue in GitHub.
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19107

The thing is that if we want to override validation we should use the specific validators that every manager has, roleValidator, userValidator, and others.
in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800273/duplicate-role-names-on-asp-net-identity-and-multi-tenancy) question you can find an implementation of the roleValidator

The last reference that I found that really help me understand how does it work was by checking the source code where you can see the default validators implementation https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src

Comment: For those wanting to override the userValidator, this question may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786399/override-validateasync-in-uservalidator-cs-for-net-core-identity-2-1/62576797#62576797